# Calculate sum from formula, wrong result

Tags: c++, sum

I have a below formula:

[image]

And I want to implement it in C++. I should get the below result:

[image]

However, I everytime I try to change something, Im gtting different results, but not the result I should get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float suma1 = 0.0, suma2 = 0.0;

    for(int j=1; j<=5; j++)
    {
        for(int k=2; k<=12; k++)
        {
            suma2 = suma2 + (sqrt(j) / (k + 1.0));
        }
        suma1 = suma2 + suma1 + 7.0;
    }

    std::cout << suma1 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare `suma2` *inside* the outer loop. Currently it’s never reset to 0.

Furthermore, you’ll generally want to use `double` instead of `float`, unless there’s a compelling reason against doing so. And *if* you use `float`, do so consistently. At the moment all the literals in your code, as well as the result of `sqrt`, are still `double`s, and will be converted to `float` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`suma2` is never reset to zero, so it ends up containing the sum of *all* inner sums.

How to fix: add `suma2 = 0.0;` before the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Basic rule: do not write everything in single function, split problem to smaller elements then chance of such errors is reduced.

As point out you have forgot to reset value for `suma2`

https://godbolt.org/z/eGfr7n

Comment: Maybe worth indicating that your solution avoid nested loops, only two simple  independent loops.